# Python if else on each lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined a python object as below:

```
from io import StringIO

a = """ab: 01dvfgf
cd: 01fgvr
ab: 02hjuy
cde: 01erttt
lm: 02hjkkk"""

s = StringIO(a)
for line in s:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
ab: 01dvfgf

cde: 01fgvr

ab: 02hjuy

cd: 01erttt

lm: 02hjkkk
```

Now I only want to print lines where the 3rd and 4th character after colon (:) is 01, So my output should only return

```
ab: 01dvfgf
cd: 01fgvr
cde: 01erttt
```

Comment: `if line[3:5] == '01: print(line)'` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will do:

```
for line in s:
    if line.split(':')[1].startswith(' 01'):
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is somehow inconsistent but I recommend you to implement like this with startswith:

```
s = {"01dvfgf","01fgvr","02hjuy","01erttt","02hjkkk"}

for line in s:
    if line.startswith('01'):
        print(line)
```

Comment: This will not work in my case because I want to print line which starts with 01 after : symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most reliable thing is to split the lines around the colon and remove all leading and trailing spaces. Then you can just match the first 2 characters of the part after the colon.

```
from io import StringIO
a = """ab: 01dvfgf
cd: 01fgvr
ab: 02hjuy
cde: 01erttt
lm: 02hjkkk"""
s = StringIO(a)
for line in s:
    before, after = (l.strip() for l in line.split(":"))
    if after[:2] == '01':
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Result

```
ab: 01dvfgf
cd: 01fgvr
cde: 01erttt
```